# Override callback function in Drupal7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am using blog module. I can access it using this URL: `http://localhost/drupal/blog`. I have put some posts.

In the blog content type, I have added a field such as posted date. When I open the same URL `http://localhost/drupal/blog`, blog posts are coming using ordering on submitted date.

Now I want that posts should be list out using order by newly added field "posted_date". I don't want to change default functionality defined in the blog.pages.inc page.
please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this function in module_name.module file in the custom module.

Ex: sites/all/modules/custom/module_name/moduleName.module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function moduleName_menu() {
$items['blog'] = array(
    'title' => 'Blogs',
    'page callback' => 'blog_list',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'file' => 'page_name.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK  
  );
}
```

Create a file moduleName.pages.inc and define callback function.

Exm: sites/all/modules/custom/moduleName/moduleName.pages.inc

```
function blog_list() {
   return t('welcome blog');
}
```

I hope it will work for you cheers!